# I can't get AngularJS to work, what am I missing here?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I just started using Angular at work at I just got done installing everything on my new home computer (Angular, Visual Studio 2013 etc. etc.). I'm just trying one of the simple examples from Angular's website but I can't seem to get anything to show up correctly. For example here is what I'm doing, simple.
HTML:

```
<head>
<title>Stuff!</title>

<script src="./scripts/angular.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-app="ngApp">
    <table ng-controller="ngAppController">
        <thead>
            <tr>TaaaaZable</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
                <td>{{name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

And here is the script...Thanks in advanced, I apologize if I am just missing something stupid..

```
<script>
angular.module('ngApp', [])
.controller('ngAppController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        { name: 'John', age: 25, gender: 'boy' },
        { name: 'Jessie', age: 30, gender: 'girl' },
        { name: 'Johanna', age: 28, gender: 'girl' },
        { name: 'Joy', age: 15, gender: 'girl' },
        { name: 'Mary', age: 28, gender: 'girl' },
        { name: 'Peter', age: 95, gender: 'boy' },
        { name: 'Sebastian', age: 50, gender: 'boy' },
        { name: 'Erika', age: 27, gender: 'girl' },
        { name: 'Patrick', age: 40, gender: 'boy' },
        { name: 'Samantha', age: 60, gender: 'girl' }];
});
</script>
```

Also, this is the output in Chrome:

**TaaaaZable
{{name}}**

Comment: Double check your path: `src="./scripts/angular.min.js"` Maybe you need a double `..` instead of a single `.`?

Comment: No sir, that wasn't it, I checked that as well. I just don't understand aha.

Comment: What's the error message in the console?

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: try `<td>{{name.name}}</td>`

Comment: ReferenceError: angular is not defined index.html:2
Error: http://localhost:57467/scripts/angular.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one

Comment: Well since this works fine in a simple environment, http://jsfiddle.net/2quZU/, you need to debug more

Comment: Just did the same as @Ian and it works fine... http://jsfiddle.net/Q7L8M/. Looks like your path to angular.min.js is not being resolved.

Comment: Also, not that it matters, but I think `<tr>TaaaaZable</tr>` is invalid - it should be `<tr><td>TaaaaZable</td></tr>`

Comment: Shucks, makes sense, I appreciate it. However, theoretically, wouldn't using this work then: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: @user3779845 It should, yes. Do you get the same (or similar) error?

Comment: are you creating mvc app ?

Comment: @Ian yes I do, its complaining that angular is not defineed

Comment: The answer below was it. I moved my scripts around and its all good. Dumb mistake aha. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this as looke like you miss reference to angular.js or your script.js or both of them

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script>
angular.module('ngApp', [])
.controller('ngAppController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        { name: 'John', age: 25, gender: 'boy' },
        { name: 'Jessie', age: 30, gender: 'girl' },
        { name: 'Johanna', age: 28, gender: 'girl' },
        { name: 'Joy', age: 15, gender: 'girl' },
        { name: 'Mary', age: 28, gender: 'girl' },
        { name: 'Peter', age: 95, gender: 'boy' },
        { name: 'Sebastian', age: 50, gender: 'boy' },
        { name: 'Erika', age: 27, gender: 'girl' },
        { name: 'Patrick', age: 40, gender: 'boy' },
        { name: 'Samantha', age: 60, gender: 'girl' }];
});
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ngApp">
    <table ng-controller="ngAppController">
        <thead>
            <tr>TaaaaZable</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
                <td>{{name.name}} </td> <td>{{name.age}} </td> <td>{{name.gender}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Dumb mistake...put my script in my <head> tag and put the reference to angular.js above that and everything is gravy. Thanks a lot sir :)